# Hide attributes out of stock on product page PRESTASHOP 1.6

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need help with hiding attributes out of stock on product page when selected some of attributes. Prestashop 1.6.1.9
I did not find ready-made solution. I'm bad at programming in php and java script, I believe I should be the knowledge that would solve this problem.

For example.

Product combinations should disappear if a certain combo is not currently in stock. For example on one product we might have S M L and 5 color variations, so 15 options. But maybe we only have size M in one color. The customer has to click through each color to find what is available as all colors show up if there is even one size M color available. It's only a problem when combos are partially out of stock.

It is necessary to make it work for the block as in the screenshot.

I would be very grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.
Best Regards.
Aleksandrs

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB7hk.png)